# Pass a URL variable to Javascript function using ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, url

Basically, I'm trying to get ASP.NET to grab a variable out of the URL and use it to start a javascript function.

The user is viewing an online catalog (built with [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/), a plugin for jquery), and when a page is clicked, it goes to a webpage with all the products from that catalog page on it. There's a link there back to catalog, but when you go back the catalog starts back at page 1. If I have the link include the page number in the URL (i.e. website.com/catalog.aspx?page=4) when you go back, I believe I can grab that out of the URL and use it to have the catalog turn to that page when it loads.

I usually stick to PHP, so I'm a bit lost here. I just need to write a little code snippet that will grab the page number and fire a javascript function using the number. Is this possible?

EDIT: Code:

Here's what I've got in javascript:

```
function changePage (pagenumber) {
    $("#flipbook").turn("page", pagenumber);
}
```

The page itself is run by NetworkSolutions, so I can't give you any of the actual code from the webpage. What I came up with so far from looking around the web is this (I hope I'm not doing this completely wrong):

```
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var pagenumber = Response.QueryString['page'];
    }
</script>
```

I'm not sure if I'm getting the variable correctly, or even what to do with it after that to fire the javascript function. Thanks for any help given!

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you want to grab the page number in the querystring using javascript, if that's correct, would this help?

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Ah, I didn't think it was possible to use javascript to get query string variables. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Im using [this plugin](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/)

Example:

To get the document params:

```
var value = $(document).getUrlParam("paramName");
```

To get the params of a html-attribut (uses src attribute)

```
var value = $('#imgLink').getUrlParam("paramName");
```

it works for me. Thanks the author.

Answer (score 2):

you can use server tags as below

```
function changePage (pagenumber) {
    $("#flipbook").turn("page", <%= Request.QueryString['page'] %>);
}
```